# Custom cycling order in MySQL

Tags: mysql, order-by, sorting

Having following Foo table:

```
id | name    | group
===|=========|======
1  | "John"  | 1
2  | "Paul"  | 1
3  | "Marry" | 1
4  | "Josh"  | 1
5  | "Mike"  | 2
6  | "Kevin" | 2
7  | "Ramon" | 2
8  | "Kim"   | 2
9  | "Henry" | 3
10 | "Susan" | 3
11 | "Greg"  | 3
12 | "Julie" | 3
```

I'd like to select it having cycling order on group field. For example, when I would like to select 6 rows, query should return:

```
id | name    | group
===|=========|======
1  | "John"  | 1
5  | "Mike"  | 2
10 | "Henry" | 3
2  | "Paul"  | 1
6  | "Kevin" | 2
11 | "Susan" | 3
```

important - there are unlimited groups in the table, so using CASE or any verbose function is pointless.

Is this possible using MySQL? So far I searched for custom order functions. I also thought about to iterate over `group` ids and use this as sorting, but I'm stuck.

Comment: Please do not multipost (http://stackoverflow.com/q/28025087/1446005).